# I created a page object model but my login page is null. How can I fix that?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pom.xml

Here is my error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.InsurancePlanes.Testcases.LoginPageTest.tearDown(LoginPageTest.java:48)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:683)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runAfterGroupsConfigurations(TestInvoker.java:658)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:642)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not your code but the stack trace of your error. We need the actual java code to tell you about your error.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to line 48 (line where the error is thrown), you can initialize your LoginPage object as such:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
```

If your LoginPage takes a parameter in its constructor, be sure to pass that in. Now, you can use LoginPage methods as such:

```
// LogIn is just a sample method. this is syntax to call any method, with parameters.
loginPage.LogIn(username,password);
```

[Instantiating objects in Java](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Showing a NullPointerException and asking how to solve it, is like calling a plumber and saying "My house is broken, can you fix it?".

Somewhere in your code you are making a reference to something that is not there.
Go to the line where you have that error (shown in the stacktrace) and see what are you trying to retrieve there. Most likely is something that you haven't initialized or that no value was assigned previously.

Answer (score 0):

LoginPageTest.java:48 probably contains a reference to an object where you are calling a method on. The method fails because the object has not been instantiated or filled. Try filling the object and rerunning the code.